# Google Maps Auto-Fill Exclusion of Countries

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-cloud-platform

I am not a seasoned developer of any kind but have recently set up the Address Auto-Fill feature on our eCommerce Website through the Maps Javascript API.

It is currently returning all country addresses. Is there a way to filter only AUSTRALIAN addresses in Cloud Console?

Please explain in basic terms, I am not a developer!

I tried to edit the API in Console Cloud but it kept then throwing errors on my checkout page saying Google Maps couldn't load properly.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to limit the results of Place AutoComplete to certain countries by setting `options.componentRestrictions.country`, which can be an array of up to 5 country codes.

You haven't shared your code indicating how you are calling the API, but [their documentation does provide examples](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-multiple-countries).

```
<script>
    const AutocompleteOptions = {
        fields: [
            'address_components',
        ],
        types: ["address"],
        componentRestrictions: {
            country: ["au"],
        },
    };
    const autocompleteInstance = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
        addressLine1Input, //pass this your input field for address line 1
        AutocompleteOptions
    );
</script>
```